# Asp.net MVC Lambda Syntax Basic of Joining and Contains

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, join, filter

I have two tables

**Products**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[product] 
(
    [Id]       INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [p_name]   VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [p_desc]   VARCHAR (250) NULL,
    [p_price]  VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [p_colour] VARCHAR (70)  NULL,
    [p_cover]  VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [p_front]  VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [p_back]   VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [p_add1]   VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [p_add2]   VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [p_cat]    INT           NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_product_catagory] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([p_cat]) REFERENCES [dbo].[catagory] ([Id])
)
```

And **Catagory**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Catagory] 
(
    [Id]       INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [cat_name] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```

With the following sample data:

`Product`:

[image]

and `Catagory`:

[image]

I want to create an action method

```
public ActionResult ViewProducts(string Key)// contains category name
{
    var product = db.products.where(p => p.p_cat.contains(key));
    return View(product);
}
```

This method should return all products where category equals to key . e.g all products belongs to shirt category.

I know how to do this in SQL but lambda syntax is new for me.

Please help, thanks

Here is my model
[Click to view model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rslmu.png)

[edo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6NuO.png)

Comment: **Typo** alert: it's a "cat**e**gory" (not a "catagory")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you join Product(p_cat) and Category(Id) and filter out the records using Cateroty?

```
public ActionResult ViewProducts(string Key)// contains category name
    {
        var product = db.products
            .Join(db.categoryies, 
                p => p.p_cat,
                c => c.Id,
                (p,c) => new { Product = p, Category = c })
            .Where(x => x.Category.cat_name.Contains(key)).ToList();
        return View(product);
    }
```

Comment: local variable c cannot be declared.

Comment: Sorry its 'catagory' instead of category. Can you answer me again

Comment: but i only want product can you re-write query again thanks

Comment: My changes,  var product = db.products
                        .Join(db.catagories,
                            p => p.p_cat,
                            c => c.Id,
                            (p, c) => new { product = p, catagory = c })
                        .Where(x => x.catagory.cat_name.Contains(key)).ToList();

I only want query to return products

Comment: Hi Zeeshan..Just add .Select(x => x.Product) after .Where(x => x.Category.cat_name.Contains(key)).

Answer (score 1):

`var product = db.products.where(p => p.Categories.cat_name == key);`

Names of members may vary depending on how EF has reverse-engineered names of your tables.

Comment: product contains catagory id and catagory name is presend in catagory table.

Comment: plz see the table again. Thanks

Comment: @Zeeshanhack Forget about SQL and learn to use EF **navigation properties** (what I believe this answer is suggesting - the `product` table related **class** should have a **navigation property** pointing to `category` **class** in addition to `p_cat` FK property. Just find how the navigation property is called and use that name instead of `Categories`).

Comment: @Zeeshanhack, it would be better if you would post the `Product` class - how it was generated by EF, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your Linq Query with the one below.

```
var product = (from p in db.products
                join c in db.categoryies ON p.p_cat equals  c.Id
                 where c.cat_name.Contains(key)
                select p).ToList();
```

**Note: Names of entities may vary as per your EF entity names.**

Comment: @Zeeshanhack Okay. Please mark answer if it will work for you.